# Regular expression to match if all given words are in a string

Tags: regex

Say I have a query like this: "one two three", if I replace with spaces with | (pipe character) I can match a string if it contains one or more of those words. This is like a logical OR.

Is there something similar that does a logical AND. It should match regardless of word ordering as long as all the words are present in the string.

Unfortunately I'm away from my Mastering Regular Expressions book :(

**Edit:** I'm using Javascript and the query can contain any amount of words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try look-ahead assertions:

```
(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three)
```

But it would be better if you use three separate regular expressions or simpler string searching operations.

Comment: Emphasis on the "it would be better if...". Regexes suck at ANDs.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing really good for that.  You could fairly easily match on three occurrences of any of the words involved:

```
(?:\b(?:one|two|three)\b.*){3}
```

but that matches "one one one" as easily as "one two three".

You can use lookahead assertions like Gumbo describes.  Or you can write out the permutations, like so:

```
(?\bone\b.*\btwo\b.*\bthree\b|\btwo\b.*\bone\b.*\bthree\b|\bone\b.*\bthree\b.*\btwo\b|\bthree\b.*\bone\b.*\btwo\b|\bthree\b.*\btwo\b.*\bone\b|\btwo\b.*\bthree\b.*\bone\b)
```

which is obviously horrible.

Long story short, it's a lot better to do three separate matches.

Answer (score 2):

## Do three separate matches.

The only reason to do it in one, is if you needed it to find them in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if it needs to contain at least **one of the words** in your list

```
     let string='One red, two green and 4 orange';
     var words='one two three';
     words=words.split(' ').join('|');
     let pattern=new RegExp(`(?=(.)*?\\b(${words})\\b)((.)+)`,'g');

if(string.match(pattern)!==null){
  //string matches at least one of the words
}else{
  //string does not match any of the words
}
```

Use this if it needs to contain **all the words** in your list

```
    let string='One red, two green and 4 orange';
     var words='one two three';
     words=words.split(' ').map(function(value,index){return '(?=(.)*?\\b('+value+')\\b)'; }).join('');
     let pattern=new RegExp(`${words}((.)+)`,'g');

if(string.match(pattern)!==null){
  //string matches all words
}else{
  //string does not match all words
}
```

What it does? First it changes the string into an array and concatenates the regex in its final form then use the magic of Javascript regex variable insertion.

This will help you delegate this method even if the list of words changes dinamically.

*if you want to test it or adjust it you can do it here: [doregex.com](https://doregex.com/?urlconstruction=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#crumbstart)

*Note that you cannot replace the backtick( ` ) with any other type of quotes(simple ' or double ") or the expression will fail.