# How to deal space in search keywords? i want to match results by AND

Tags: sql, t-sql, search

I got a searchbox, the sql statment is like:

```
SELECT ..... WHERE ... LIKE '%A%'
```

but when user entered "A B" (space between A and B)

I want to select all records which content contains both A and B.

But I can not write:

```
.... LIKE '%A%B%'
```

because it won't match string that B occurs first like: "ilikeBnotA"

It should be

```
...LIKE '%A%' AND ...LIKE '%B%'
```

But the user may input more than one spance, like "A B C ...", so i need to write a loop, contacting every keyword into:

```
AND ...LIKE '%keyword%'
```

I don't think it's a good idea, i doubt it may cause performance issues when searching large string (like a blog post content).

Is there any good solution to this problem? Dow do search engines do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a split function:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[f_split]
(
@param nvarchar(max), 
@delimiter char(1)
)
returns @t table (val nvarchar(max), seq int)
as
begin
set @param += @delimiter

;with a as
(
select cast(1 as bigint) f, charindex(@delimiter, @param) t, 1 seq
union all
select t + 1, charindex(@delimiter, @param, t + 1), seq + 1
from a
where charindex(@delimiter, @param, t + 1) > 0
)
insert @t
select substring(@param, f, t - f), seq from a
option (maxrecursion 0)
return
end
```

Then you can search like this:

```
-- declaring a tablevariable to represent your table
declare @yourtable table(id int identity(1,1), searchcol varchar(50))
insert @yourtable values('abc')
insert @yourtable values('za')
insert @yourtable values('az')
insert @yourtable values('zz')
declare @input varchar(50)
set @input = 'a b c'

-- show if one or more match exists
select * from @yourtable a 
where exists (select 1 from f_split(@input, ' ') b 
              where a.searchcol like '%'+ b.val + '%')


--show only if all matches exists
select * from @yourtable a 
where not exists (select 1 from clausens_base.dbo.f_split(@input, ' ') b 
              where not a.searchcol like '%'+ b.val + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267935/471214) regular expressions [with SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S2) and write [a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035557/471214) to [match all given strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082333/471214):

```
(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below written code should do in case of one space char is there and your search string is in a variable called @a

```
     ...LIKE LEFT(@a,CHARINDEX(' ',@a)) AND ... LIKE RIGHT(@a,CHARINDEX(' ',@a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another column in your table, say keywords, and when inserting data also create the keyword of your data by removing whitespace characters and insert to this column.
When searching search the keyword in this column.

```
create function createKeyword(@data nvarchar(256))
returns nvarchar(256)
as
begin
-- remove whitespace characters
return @kword
end
```

And when searching use

```
t.keywords like '%' + dbo.createKeyword(@data) + '%'
```

Comment: My bad I am sorry, this will not match 'ilikeBnotA'